# partial imputation with missForest

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `missForest` package in R to partially impute a dataset. In detail, I would like to impute all the metric variables but leave a few columns alone. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried something like `m[,1:4] <- missForest(m[,1:4])` ?

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Sadly I can't because the dataset I'm using is company data :(.

Comment: @Glassjawed: so cook up a toy example with a standard dataset like mtcars or iris or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I have a potential solution, if I'm understanding your question correctly. I am going to provide you some code that should be fully reproducible.

```
## Get some data...
data(iris)

## The data contains four continuous and one categorical variable.
## Artificially produce missing values using the 'prodNA' function:
set.seed(81)
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)

## Impute missing values for just the first four columns of data
iris.mis[,1:4] <- missForest(iris.mis)$ximp[,1:4]
```

Let me know if an approach like this works. If it doesn't work, see if you can use some example code to show why.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, You need to leave few columns and impute other columns with `missForest` function. Simple solution is

```
imputedData <- missForest(dataset[c( 2, 3)])
dataset <- data.frame(dataset[1], imputedData)
```

pass columns need to be imputed(here 2,3) and then combine it back.